# Convert Decimal to Hex or Unicode using Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, unicode, decimal, emoji

the problem i'm facing is when i inputting emoji from an android device to display on a browser, the emoji is converted its form of Decimal code like `&#128153; &#128153; &#128153;`. is there any way to detect the decimal code then convert it to Hex or Unicode with javascript? because with Hashtag in front of the number, it might lead to confusion as hashtag input.

I've used the toString() method but it doesn't seem to solve the problem

`decimalNumber.toString( radix )`

Answer (score 0):

maybe use  `\u----` where ---- is hexacode ( in utf8 string)  ?